# Subject: Recreating Blender's Dynamic Mesh Intersection Visualization

Tags: mesh

[image: blender ornage lines]

"I'm trying to access or mimic the orange boundary lines Blender generates in Object Mode to indicate overlapping mesh interactions (see the attached picture).  Ideally, I'd like to extract the precise mesh data these lines represent, or at least the logic behind their calculation, for use in scripting custom mesh cutting operations. My Goal:

Direct Data Access: If the orange lines are based on true mesh elements, how can I locate these mesh components within Blender's data structures?
Algorithmic Recreation: Alternatively, can someone shed light on potential algorithms within Blender responsible for calculating these intersection boundaries with high accuracy during interactive object manipulation?
Even Partial Clues: Any information about relevant Blender development areas or code sections dealing with similar visualizations would be incredibly helpful.
Background: I've investigated Blender's Python API in the following areas (collision detection, viewport rendering, etc.). While helpful, nothing seems to provide direct access to the  fine-grained overlap visuals in question. Could Blender be doing this as part of an internal step of its rendering process that isn't directly accessible using the public APIs?

Thanks for any insights and suggestions!"

[Link to the .obj file if of any interest](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1llFD_ro_PL1as_gN8VqQbS5GOGkDm4i4/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: No one has any suggestion? :)

Comment: Maybe mimic it with a voronoi texture?